# Web scraping and Xpath on local install of WordPress

Tags: ios, wordpress, xpath

I am a part of the team that is building a WordPress webpage for a university project, we are also trying to develop some iOS apps for this website.

For this purpose I want to scrape the pages and posts in the website and convert them to XML format so that the iOS app can access it and use it to populate content within the app.

Comment: Try adding /feed/ to your site's URL. Viola, it's in XML (via RSS). If you're wanting more help than that, you're going to have to be a lot more specific...